# How to publish Enterprise Application without plist in iOS

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8.1, ota, ios-enterprise

We uploaded our app ipa and plist file on a webserver and able to install in below 8.0 versions and 8.3 versions.
It looks iOS Bug with 8.1, 8.2 versions, not able to install the app from our webserver. It says "App name couldn't be downloaded at this time" all the times. When we upload the same ipa file in http://www.diawi.com/ , https://www.installrapp.com and able to install the App. So how they are doing this just by using ipa file, not even asking to upload plist file.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?

Comment: No @Pierre , without plist we have not achieved. We have fixed the issue "App name couldn't be downloaded at this time", i.e, issue with server firewall.